# Displaced elements with LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am making a simple calculator using `LinearLayout`.

The problem is that it looks like this :

[image]

Instead of like this:

[image]

I simply want it to look like in the second image. I don't get why it doesn't.

Please, can someone help me with this?

[Here's](https://www.pastiebin.com/5914c6463cac1) the pastie with the `xml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `android:baselineAligned="false"` that you have to apply to all of your nested `LinearLayouts`.

See enhanced layout [here](https://www.pastiebin.com/5914c820196b4).

Answer (score 1):

use this layout:

use layout `weightSum` and `layout_weight` properly in your child buttons to align them with required space:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.tsvetan.exercise_4_calculator.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clear"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
            android:onClick="clear"
            android:text="C"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/number"
            android:layout_width="306dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"
            android:text="0"
            android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
            android:textSize="30sp" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:weightSum="5">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/but7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".8"
            android:onClick="seven"
            android:text="7" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/but8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".8"
            android:onClick="eight"
            android:text="8" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/but9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".8"
            android:onClick="nine"
            android:text="9" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/plus"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.2"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:onClick="onOperatorClick"
            android:padding="0px"
            android:text="+"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/multiply"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.2"
            android:onClick="onOperatorClick"
            android:text="*"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:weightSum="5">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/but4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".8"
            android:onClick="four"
            android:text="4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/but5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".8"
            android:onClick="five"
            android:text="5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/but6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".8"
            android:onClick="six"
            android:text="6" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/minus"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.2"
            android:onClick="onOperatorClick"
            android:padding="0px"
            android:text="-"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/division"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.2"
            android:onClick="onOperatorClick"
            android:text="/"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:weightSum="5">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/but1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".8"
            android:onClick="one"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/but2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".8"
            android:onClick="two"
            android:text="2" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/but3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".8"
            android:onClick="three"
            android:text="3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/equals"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2.4"
            android:onClick="onOperatorClick"
            android:padding="0px"
            android:text="="
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColorLink="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:weightSum="5">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/but0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.6"
            android:onClick="zero"
            android:text="0" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/butMult"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".8"
            android:onClick="point"
            android:text="."
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

**output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put height to all of your buttons. Just put the height of linear layout and the rest will be match_parent. You will get what you want:

[image: example]